# Handling Id Uniqueness With a Single Key or with a Composite Key

Tags: mysql, architecture

First off, I'm new to architecting a DB and I'm looking for help from people who are more experienced and are able to point out gotchas and issues that I might not see.

I'm building out a new DB schema and I'm weighing the benefits of using composite keys for uniqueness vs a single primary key.

Here is an example. An Owner owns things, Things have components, Components have descriptions.

#### Approach 1 - Composite Key

One way I can architect this is by giving the owner an `INT` id, `OwnerId`, and then anything they own a `SMALLINT` id, OwnedThingId. The result is that each owner has `MAX(SMALLINT)` things they can own. The other result is that the `OwnedThingId`'s are repeated in the db. For example, the table would have many different `OwnedThingId`'s of `1`. Uniqueness is only attainable by composing the `OwnedThingId` with the `OwnerId`. In this case the PK would be (`OwnerId`, `OwnedThingId`).

[image: Approach1]

#### Approach 2 - Single Key

The other way I can architect this is by making the `OwnedThingId` bigger, say an `INT`, and make that field unique throughout the whole table. In this case there would only be one thing with an id of `1`, regardless of how many owners there are. The result is that there is a limit of `MAX(INT)` for **all owners**. However, the record is now easier to refer to since I only need an `OwnedThingId` instead of both an `OwnerId` and `OwnedThingId`.

[image: Approach2]

#### Approach 1 - Pros & Cons

Pro: I like approach 1 because it has the potential to take less space with smaller keys and because it's more contained. The number of owners in the system doesn't really matter, the `OwnedThingId`'s available to the owners doesn't change. It also mirrors the real world a bit better. i.e. Student id 12 isn't the same student at all the schools ever.
Con: Since multiple ids are required to determine uniqueness, there is the potential for a future table to store and need to refer to X number of id's instead of just storing one id.

#### Approach 2 - Pros & Cons

Pro: Only one field is needed to confer uniqueness. A Record is unique across all owners. There is also less to keep track of, a future table would only need to store and refer to the one unique id.

Con: It can take more space because it uses bigger int values. Each owner that claims an id, reduces the pool of available ids for all owners.

#### Conclusion

Like I said, I'm leaning towards approach 1, but I get the feeling like I might be shooting myself in the foot as time goes on and the system grows. Thus I am reaching out to those with more experience in architecture than I to inform me of potential gotcha's or reasons why I should consider one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your verbal description implies

- These "Entities":  Owner, Thing, Component -- each being a table.
- These "many-to-many Relations": OwnerThing, ThingComponent -- each being a table

Entities have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

A many-to-many table is likely to be no more than

```
 CREATE TABLE OwnerThing (
     owner_id ...,
     thing_id ...,
     PRIMARY KEY(owner_id, thing_id),
     INDEX(thing_id, owner_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Note that `id` for a many-to-many table is actually a de-optimizer.  Those composite indexes are optimal.

Entities, on the other hand, usually need

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(...)  -- as needed by the queries
```

Optimization is determined more by the queries than by the schema. Please provide some typical `SELECTs`.

More in my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

**Relations**  On the other hand...

If a `Thing` is owned by only `Owner` and a `Component` exists in only one `Thing, then you have "one-to-many" relationships.  Such should be handled by` owner_id`in`Things`and`thing_id` in Components.

Comment: Are you suggesting storing the relationship in a join table? I was planning on nixing the join table and storing the relationship directly on the entity table itself.

Comment: @jeremysawesome - many-to-many requires an extra table; one-to-many does not.

Comment: I was confused by the name "OwnerThing".  I added a paragraph.

Comment: Interesting moment... does defining the backward index as unique may provide some profit? Of course this provides insert/update overhead due to excess uniqueness check - but maybe there is a case when the index uniqueness may cause in execution plan change to the more effective one?